# a/an substitution in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I was wondering if there is a conditional command that I can use in latex (e.g., \ifthenelse) that would allow me to, in one case, use the word 'a' and in another use the word 'an' based on the whether or not the following word starts with a vowel.

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Comment: Now on tex.sx: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6627/a-an-substitution-in-latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX provides a plain \if that compares letters. The following will work, unless you do something like \AOrAn \myapplecommand, which will give unexpected results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\AOrAn[1]{%
  a%
  \@for\@vowel:=a,e,i,o,u,y,A,E,I,O,U,Y\do{%
    \expandafter\ifx\@vowel#1%
      n%
    \fi
  } % keep this space
  #1%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\AOrAn apple, \AOrAn orange, \AOrAn banana.


an apple, an orange, a banana.
\end{document}
```

You cannot manually enforce an "an" like this, but you should be able to suppress it by writing \AOrAn {}university.

(Edited to take remark re exceptional cases into account.)

Comment: No good on this. 'a' works but not 'an'. For example, it gives me a thing but not an apple.

Comment: @Raffi Khatchadourian: funny that, works fine here as copy-and-pasted from above.

Comment: It may have something to do with using a command as the noun. For example, my code would read \AOrAn \Noun.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian: In this case you would need to expand the `\Noun` first. If it is a simple macro with the letter as the first token in its expansion (not another macro or such), you can use `\expandafter\AOrAn\Noun`. Otherwise some more tricks are needed (with \edef or such).

Answer (score 6):

This won't work in general, because the decision to use *a* or *an* is based, not mechanically on the letter that follows the article, but on its pronunciation.  Thus 'an uncle', but 'a university' and 'an honour'.

Comment: Good point. I have amended to that effect, we'd have to include h an an honorary vowel and flag exceptions.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but it would at least reduce the number of cases in which a change would have to be made.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.physics.wm.edu/~norman/latexhints/conditional_macros.html)  you have some examples to use conditionals in Latex.